# What is ** in C?

Tags: c

the `*` is used for pointers, but what is `**` used for? I found this question in a video I was watching on implementing a hash table passed into `main` as `char **argv`.

Comment: Pointer to pointer. Pointers point to stuff. Sometimes that stuff is other pointers.

Comment: Pointer to pointer. Like array of string in case of argv (no hashtable) or array of arrays and so on. Use optional book about C for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pointer to a pointer. The most common case is

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

Since pointers can point to an array, pointers to pointers are commonly used to arrays of arrays.

Also used as function arguments when setting the value of a pointer.